# SQL Server StoredProc vs UDF inline table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, inline, user-defined-functions

I have written a complex query that will return me a list of IDs. Now I want to re-use this query so that I join the results with another query. For that I plan to put this into a Stored Proc or an UDF and then use it to insert into a temp table.

Something like below

1) Put the query in a Stored Proc and insert it into temp table

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP
EXEC SP_COMPLEX(@PARAM1,@PARAM2...@@PARAMN)
```

2) Put the query in a UDF and insert it into temp table

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT ID_LIST FROM DBO.UDF_COMPLEX(@PARAM1,@PARAM2...@@PARAMN)
```

I can't see significance difference between the two when I run them for a result of 1000 IDs. But in real implementation the result may be a million rows.

For performance which one would be better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than guessing, I suggest you compare the execution plans for both techniques.

> User defined functions can be
>   convenient, they can also sometimes
>   cause performance to suffer. This
>   problem with them is that they use
>   row-by-row processing, similar to a
>   cursor, instead of a set-based
>   operation. So if the result set of
>   your query, then the performance
>   impact will be small. But if the
>   result set is large, then performance
>   could very well become a problem.
>   Generally speaking, if you are using a
>   user defined function, you will want
>   to avoid using them with large result
>   sets. Use a stored procedure instead.

One way to improve performance of scalar valued User-Defined Functions is by converting them to table-valued ones.

Answer (score 0):

I found using an inline table valued function and directly joining it is the better and efficient option than the options I had asked in the question.
Something like

```
SELECT MYTABLE.MYFIELD FROM MYTABLE, DBO.UDF_COMPLEX(@PARAM1,@PARAM2...@@PARAMN) MYQUERY
WHERE MYTABLE.KEYVALUE = MYQUERY.KEYVALUE
```

Comment: The below syntax is actually very inefficient 

INSERT INTO #TEMP 

EXEC SP_COMPLEX(@PARAM1,@PARAM2...@@PARAMN)